# How can I resolve this undefined reference of a template member function without bringing all of the relevant code to the header?

Tags: c++, templates

in `foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

enum Rat
{
    A,
    B
};

class Foo
{
public:
    template<Rat r>
    int aMemberFunc(int, int, int);
};

#endif
```

in `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"

namespace {
template<Rat r>
int helper(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b*((int) r);
}
}

template<Rat r>
int Foo::aMemberFunc(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + helper<r>(b,c);
}
```

in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    Foo test;
    cout << test.aMemberFunc<B>(1,2,3) << endl;
}
```

I compile with `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp` and I get:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `int Foo::aMemberFunc<(Rat)1>(int, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would prefer not to move stuff to the header because that brings along the helper and a lot of baggage, I tried to add a file `fooimpl.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.cpp"

template int Foo::aMemberFunc<A>(int,int,int);
template int Foo::aMemberFunc<B>(int,int,int);
```

and then compile with `g++ fooimpl.cpp main.cpp foo.cpp`

This was per the suggestion of Dietmar (thanks!) but as soon as I add a function `void rand();` in the header of `foo.h` and `void rand() {}` in `foo.cpp` the above trick yields this error:

foo.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Foo::rand()'
/tmp/ccoCtGMk.o:fooimpl.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

how do i work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your function, not specialize it:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.cpp"

template int Foo::aMemberFunc<A>(int,int,int);
template int Foo::aMemberFunc<B>(int,int,int);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, what you call "instantiate", the standard calls "specialize" ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: according to 14.7.2 [temp.explicit] paragraph 1 I'm explicitly instantiating a specialization.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks that compiled, but I edited the question to the real life case of Foo actually having other normal functions in which case the abaove trick gives me another compiler error i cant seem to get around...

Comment: @DietmarKühl nvm i got rid of impl and threw the template instatiations into the .C and that did the trick thanks!